# Building a Queue of student lists with a Double link list

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue

Sorry for all the questions, but this function is giving my a lot of problems. I've almost got it complete, but I have one last bug. The point of this function is to pop 3 students, once a day. One that day is complete, it will move onto the next day and pop the next 3 (With the possibility of moving onto the next Queue list). My num2 represents the day and every time it finishes 3 students, it should increment the day by 1.

When I run the program, I get some weird results. The day will increment fine if I stay on the same Queue list, but when I jump, it gets stuck on the first increment. Example:

I have two Queues lists

1st Queue list: Rachel, Ed, Amy, Matt
2nd Queue list: John, Daniel, Nick

Result:

Day1:
Rachel,
Ed,
Amy

Day2:

Matt, is the last student...
John,
Daniel,

Day 2:

Nick, is the last student..

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Main function

```
    int s = 0;
    int d = 1;
    cout<<"How many Student do you currently have appointments with? "<<endl;
    cin>>s;
    cout<<"What day would you like to start seeing students?"<<endl;
    cin>>d;
    cout<<"Day "<<d<<endl;


    s = priority1->enqueue(s,d);
    s = priority2->enqueue(s,d);
    s = priority3->enqueue(s,d);
    s = priority4->enqueue(s,d);
```

Queue function call

```
int enqueue(int x, int& m)
{
    n->pop_front(x,m);
}
```

LinkList Pop_front function

```
int pop_front(int x, int& m)
    {
        int num = x;
        int num2 = m;
        string value;
        while(front != NULL)
            {   
                if(num == 3)
                {
                    num = 0;
                    num2++;
                    cout<<endl<<endl<<"Day "<<num2<<endl;
                }
                while(num<3)
                {
                    Node *temp = front;
                    if(front->next)
                    {   value = front->name;
                        front = front->next;
                        front->prev = NULL;
                        size--;
                        delete temp;
                        cout<<value<<", "<<endl;
                        num++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    cout<<endl;
                    if(front->next == NULL)
                    {
                        value=front->name;
                        front = NULL;
                        back = NULL;
                        delete temp;
                        size--;
                        cout<<value<<", is the last student in this priority Queue list"<<endl;
                        num++;
                        return num;
                    }
                }
}
    }
```

Comment: Why not just use std::list?

Comment: Building my own for a project

Comment: That doesn't explain why your project cannot use std::list. That class has already been debugged by the class library authors.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `m` which represents the days by `reference`:

```
int pop_front(int x, int& m)
```

but then you are using `num2` in the body of the function:

```
num2++;
cout<<endl<<endl<<"Day "<<num2<<endl;
```

and so you are not passing an updated `m` on each call to `enqueue`. The reference only applies to `m`, when you assign `m` to `num2` you are creating a new variable and they are not linked and so changes to `num2` will not be reflected for `m`.